# How to copy .exe from C++ project to the output directory of a C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, reference, project

Say you have a Visual Studio solution containing 2 projects:

1. Project A: C++ console application
2. Project B: C# console application

Project B depends upon the output `.exe` of Project A. Is there a way to set this `.exe` to be automatically copied to Project B's output folder during build?

Comment: Maybe you can watch the folder and copy it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Buildevents in the properties for the project.

Here you can define Post and Prebuild Tasks with Wildcards.

like:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)UploaderClient\bin\Debug\Plugins\$(TargetFileName)"
```

Comment: You can indeed use the wildcards `*` and `?`. `$(TargetPath)` etc are known as MSBuild macro's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in VS go into the project properties for A.  Look under "Configuration Properties" for a sub item of "Build Events", expand that and add a "Post-Build Event".  These are simple dos commands, so you can just copy the .exe where-ever you want.